# d3.js nested selection, doesn't work

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nested

So this is my code, I have an array of arrays, and they contain an object with 4 points, so I can draw a line using svg, when I tested the code using only an array it worked fine, but I can't make it work with an array of arrays, any help would be deeply appreciated.

```
var circle = svgContainer.selectAll("svg").data(mainMt);
 console.log(circle);
 console.log("Linea");
 var line = circle.data(function(d) { return d; })
.enter().append("line")
                      .attr("x1", function (d) { return d.x1; })
                      .attr("y1", function (d) { return d.y1; })
                      .attr("x2", function (d) { return d.x2; })
                      .attr("y2", function (d) { return d.y2; })
                      .attr("stroke-width", 2)
                      .attr("stroke", "black");

                      console.log(line);
```

Comment: You're missing the nested select. See [this tutorial](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest/).

Comment: IOkay I added the select, and it doesn't throw any error, however my line variable comes out as an empty array, I need to get each object of the array within the array so that's my approach into getting those objects, any workaround or something I'm missing. I already read that tutorial a couple of times, but I'm pretty new to d3.

Comment: Can you provide a complete example that demonstrates the problem please?

Comment: http://www.carshel.com/tramonte/
Basically we want a bunch of lines to transition into anothers, but I need to solve the drawing first, I have an array of arrays, and these arrays contain objects with x1, x2, y1, y2. I'm trying to get those coordinates so I can draw the lines and transition from there. I provided the link in which I'm testing.

Comment: You need to select something in the nested select! It looks like you want `.selectAll("line")`.

Comment: Got it, but still returns an empty array. Not quite sure if the data is getting lost in the very first select...

Comment: You need to operate on the enter selection for the top-level selection. Something like `svgContainer.selectAll("g.lines").data(mainMt).enter().append("g").attr("class", "lines").selectAll("line").data(function(d) { return d; }).enter().append...`

Comment: You're a genius man! Refresh the page, it looks so awesome! Thanks alot!

Comment: Great! I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things missing -- first, you need to operate on the enter selection of the top-level selection and second, select things for the nested selection:

```
svgContainer
  .selectAll("g.lines")
  .data(mainMt)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class"‌​, "lines")
  .selectAll("line").data(function(d) { return d; })
  .enter()
  .append("line")
  ...
```